# How can I split returned results in while loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am developing an application where I need to return result of two rows and create a  tag in middle of them to show a VS icon (this is competition). At some stage I need to split results correct? How would that be achieved,

Result should be like

```
<div class='hero_comp'>

        <div class='hero_comp_img'><img src='images/$picture' alt='$name' width='200' height='200'/></div>    

        <div class='hero_comp_txt'>$reason</div>

        <div class='hero_comp_btn'><form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary border-radius-zero' name='vote'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Vote for me</button></form></div>

<div class='vs'></div>


<div class='hero_comp'>

        <div class='hero_comp_img'><img src='images/$picture' alt='$name' width='200' height='200'/></div>    

        <div class='hero_comp_txt'>$reason</div>

        <div class='hero_comp_btn'><form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary border-radius-zero' name='vote'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Vote for me</button></form></div>
```

this is what I've done so far

```
$select_comp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nominate WHERE accepted='1' ORDER BY id DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($select_comp) >=2 ) {

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_comp)) {

    $picture=$row['picture'];
    $reason=$row['reason'];
    $id=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];

    echo"

    <div class='hero_comp'>

    <div class='hero_comp_img'><img src='images/$picture' alt='$name' width='200' height='200'/></div>    

    <div class='hero_comp_txt'>$reason</div>

    <div class='hero_comp_btn'><form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary border-radius-zero' name='vote'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Vote for me</button></form></div>

    </div>

    ";

    }
}
```

Comment: What is a VS icon? How do you want the results to be split? What's the current output? What's the expected output? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23785983/edit) your question to include these details.

Comment: Also, just for your information: `ext/mysql` extension is deprecated. You should port your code to use MySQLi/PDO if you want to ensure continued functionality of your project/application.

Comment: VS icon is a static div placed between two results, im returning 2 rows and div needs to be in middle of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to accomplish is to loop through results and show Result 1 VS Result 2 then move on to the next pairing, you could add in a counter in your loop to figure out where you're at in the pattern.

```
$count=1;
$select_comp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nominate WHERE accepted='1' ORDER BY id DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($select_comp) >=2 ) {

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_comp)) {

    $picture=$row['picture'];
    $reason=$row['reason'];
    $id=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];

    echo"

    <div class='hero_comp'>

    <div class='hero_comp_img'><img src='images/$picture' alt='$name' width='200' height='200'/></div>    

    <div class='hero_comp_txt'>$reason</div>

    <div class='hero_comp_btn'><form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary border-radius-zero' name='vote'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Vote for me</button></form></div>

    </div>

    ";

        if ($count==1) {

            /* Display VS Button since the 1st result has been posted, increase count to 2 for next loop */

            $count=2;

        } elseif ($count==2) {

            /* If you want to insert something to separate the Result 1 VS Result 2 just echoed, go for it here, otherwise we set the count back to 1. */

            $count=1;

        }
    }
}
```

This would force a 1 vs 2, 3 vs 4, 5 vs 6 pairing from your table since you're sorting by ID.  If you wanted to specify a different pairing there are a few other ways you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add your results to two different arrays.

After the while loop you can do two foreaches (http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and split your data that way.

An example:
$select_comp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nominate WHERE accepted='1' ORDER BY id DESC");
    if (mysql_num_rows($select_comp) >= 2) {

```
    $rows = array();
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_comp)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Present the data as you wish here
    // The first row will be $rows[0] and the seconds $rows[1]
}
```